# Type mismatch when using map on a zipped list in Scala

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

Consider this code :

```scala
  /** Takes a list and turns it into an infinite looping stream. */
  def loop(l: List[Char]): LazyList[Char] = {
      l.to(LazyList)  #:::loop(l)
  }

  /** Encodes a sequence of characters with a looped key. */
  def codec(message: Seq[Char], key: Seq[Char], cipher: (Char, Char) => Char): Seq[Char] = {
    val loopedKey = loop(key.toList)
    val mergedMessage = message.toList zip loopedKey
    val xorResult = mergedMessage.map(cipher)
    xorResult.toSeq
  }
```

The loop function is correct, but the function named `codec` yield the following error when compiled :

```scala
[error]  type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (Char, Char) => Char
[error]  required: ((Char, Char)) => ?
[error]     val xorResult = mergedMessage.map(cipher)
```

I don't understand why the `required` part says : `((Char, Char)) => ?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(Char, Char) => Char` is a function accepting 2 `Chars` and returning `Char` while [`zip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/Seq.html#zip%5BB%5D(that:scala.collection.IterableOnce%5BB%5D):CC%5B(A@scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance,B)%5D) will result in a collection of [tuples](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/tuples.html) `(Char, Char)`. One option is to change `cipher` type to accept a tuple - `((Char, Char)) => Char`:

```scala
def codec(message: Seq[Char], key: Seq[Char], cipher: ((Char, Char)) => Char): Seq[Char] = ...
```

Without changing the signature - access tuple elements directly:

```scala
val xorResult = mergedMessage.map(t => cipher(t._1, t._2))
```

Or just use [`tupled`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Function2.html#tupled:((T1,T2))=%3ER):

```
val xorResult = mergedMessage.map(cipher.tupled)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decided to use `tupled` and it works fine.